# Is there anyway to dynamically access an object from a Utility Class in EXTJS?

Tags: extjs, global-variables

My code structure is as follows->

MyApp-> app -> model, view, controller, store, utils

I have the following utility class created for my validation errors:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.shared.utils.GlobalStrings', {
         AmountLimitViolation: "Amount Limit Violated",
         DurationLimitViolation: "Duration Limit Violated"
});
```

I am trying to get the strings dynamically in the following way, but they keep coming up undefined:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.ViewController', {
        extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

        violationCheck: function (tradelimit, tradelimitViolations){
            let me = this,
            tradeViolationMessage = "";

            if(tradelimit > 0){
                for(i = 0; i < tradelimitViolations.length; i++){
                    violationString = tradelimitViolations[i] + "Violation";
                    tradeViolationMessage += GlobalStrings.violationString;
                }
            }
        }
});
```

tradelimitViolations is a string that would contain something like: ("AmountLimit", "DurationLimit")

So is there any method I could use to get AmountLimitViolation and DurationLimitViolation dynamically without having to resort to using a long list of conditional statements? Because I'm just showing two of the many violation errors I have.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you are "indexing" into GlobalStrings. The dot operator uses the text to the right as the key, but you have a variable holding your key.

Try this:

```
        for(i = 0; i < tradelimitViolations.length; i++){
            violationString = tradelimitViolations[i] + "Violation";
            tradeViolationMessage += GlobalStrings[violationString];
        }
```